# Schema change with sqlite database and slite-net

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I am currently using a SQLite database with the SQLite-NET library in my Windows Phone 8.1 application.  I was wondering if anyone has any best practices on how to accomplish table schema changes when upgrading between app versions.

Is my only option to manually create the raw SQL statements to update the schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a small thank you to the SO community, I have provided the main code I use to handle schema changes.  Note this will handle database upgrades from any earlier versions to the latest version (even if the user skips versions in between).  Database downgrades are not handled.  I should probably sprinkle in a little more error checking | try/catch statements.

In my sqlite helper class I have the declarations below:

```
private SQLiteConnection _db;

// Start from 1 and increment this number whenever DB schema changes are made
private const int LATEST_DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
```

Then my main upgrade method is:

```
private void DoUpgradeDb(int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            for (int vFrom = oldVersion; vFrom < newVersion; vFrom++)
            {
                switch (vFrom)
                {
                    case 1: // Upgrade from v1 to v2
                        UpgradeV1AlterPersonAddColumnAge();
                        UpgradeV1AnotherSchemaChange();
                        break;
                    case 2: // Upgrade from v2 to v3
                        UpgradeV2CreateTableHobbies();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            // Save the new version number to local storage
            App.AppSettingsService.SetDatabaseVersion(newVersion);
        }
```

As you see above, I like to place individual changes made in each version into its own method, so I could define the `UpgradeV2CreateTableHobbies()` method as:

```
    private void UpgradeV2CreateTableHobbies()
    {
        _db.CreateTable<Hobbies>();
    }
```

Of course you also need to remember to make the same schema changes when the DB is created from scratch (e.g. new install) not just when updated.

When the next upgrade is needed, you can increment the `LATEST_DATABASE_VERSION` constant.  I check if a version upgrade is needed each time I instantiate my Sqlite helpder class (since I use a singleton pattern), you could do something like:

```
    private bool UpgradeDbIfRequired()
    {
        bool wasUpgradeApplied = false;
        // I wrote a GetDatabaseVersion helper method that reads the version (as nullable int) from local app settings.
        int? currentVersion = App.AppSettingsService.GetDatabaseVersion();
        if (currentVersion.HasValue && currentVersion.Value < LATEST_DATABASE_VERSION)
        {
                // Upgrade to latest version
                DoUpgradeDb(currentVersion.Value, LATEST_DATABASE_VERSION);
                wasUpgradeApplied = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Already on latest version
            return false;
        }

        return wasUpgradeApplied;
    }
```